# Fantasy book series where some people could mindspeak with some animals. Some characters could only die by drowning, some were knights

Tags: story-identification, books

Some characters were knights. Some could mindspeak with some animals.
One character was in WW2 and never aged. Others lived like Native Americans.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books, and when do you think they might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about any of the covers?

Comment: If you recall any other details about the plot or characters, please [edit] your question to add them in. The more info you can provide, the better.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like it might be Robert Adams' [*Horseclans*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?148) series, set in a post-nuclear war North America, where the titular clans arose on the Great Plains.

Some members of the clans have telepathic contact with their horses and the sabertooth tigers that also roam the plains.

Several significant characters are Undying, who can only be killed by beheading or drowning.

One of the Undying is Bookermann, who was once a German army officer; it could be he you are thinking of.

There are more details on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseclans) for the series.

Comment: That the OP refers to the telepathy as *mindspeak* strongly suggests that it was indeed the Horseclans series, and the central character of the series (Milo Moray, spelled differently in places) had memories going back to WWII. Bookermann also remembered WWII (and was on the other side of the war). The titular people lived as nomads in the US Central Plains.

Comment: Other details: Horses, re-created saber-toothed cats, many species of mustelids, and orcas are shown to have mindspeak. Also, Robert Adams was given to polemics that at times were anti-communist or anti-Christian.